# Change Magento CMS Home page

Tags: magento, content-management-system, clone, groupon

I am using this [groupon clone](http://grouponclone.contussupport.com) from contus

I am try to change the **cms home page** .Which as what i have observed can be found in

> System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages

I tried changing the **CMS Home Page** .i chose the template that i made in

> CMS > Pages

I am expecting the template to be loaded .and ugh after several tries, clearing the cache and even changing the **Default Web URL** into the templates **URL Key** .it didn't work

any suggestions?

Here's a screenshot of the default cms_home_page

[image]

I tried editing the **config.xml** in the

> app\code\core\Mage\Cms\etc

I changed the **default > web > default > cms_home_page** node into the **coming-soon** URL key .Still didn't work

I can access the http://127.0.0.1/mg/coming-soon/ page and the http://127.0.0.1/mg/home/ page as well .I just wonder, why the settings i applied in the admin (and can also be seen in the db) doesn't work.

Comment: What version of Magento? Which flavor: CE? EE? And what do you see that makes you say, "it didn't work"?

Comment: sorry im kinda new with these stuff .the varsion of the contus groupon clone is 4.3.2.6 .the magento version as what i see in the release notes is 1.4.1.0 and it is EE

Comment: Based on what I see here, as long as your CMS page's url key is coming-soon that should be the page which loads when you go to your base_url. What are you saying when you visit your base_url (i.e. homepage)?

Comment: yeah that's what is supposed to happen right? .but whenever i load the base url (e.g. localhost/mg/) it still loads the localhost/mg/index.php/home instead of the index.php/coming-soon

Comment: You should change the base_url from localhost to 127.0.0.1 - you can find it in core_config_data table.

Comment: can't i just change it inside the admin panel? i can access everything .ok will try

Answer (score 3):

> you can simply go to **system >> configuration >>** and click on the **web** which is left in your window under general.
>
> than click on **Default Pages** and set **CMS Home Page**
>
> Second thing, You have to do "enable" this page and you can do it from
> **cms >> pages** and click on the page which you have selected, than set **status >> enable**

Answer (score 1):

The unique identifier in the CMS > Manage Content section just needs to be a unique string in the context of a store view. You should NOT use the frontname of a core module there (e.g. "cms"). Change your url key to something unique, and head to System > Configuration. Select Web. As long as the **Default Web URL** is set to `cms`, `cms/index`, or `cms/index/index` you should be able to simply choose the desired CMS page from the **Default Web URL** dropdown. Make sure you check other configuration scope settings (dropdown at top left) in case there is  a rude setting set at a lower level.

FYI, what you "make" in the Manage Pages section are routes with content as opposed to  "templates" (in Magento parlance). Templates are PHTML files under `app/design`.

Comment: @benmarks are you sure about _Default Web URL dropdown_ ? because I didn't find the one and what I found was just a textfield @ System-> Configuration->Web

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer to those who reach this page;

If you see this behaviour you should check the store switcher in your top left. Choose your store and check the config for it.

Probably it's not using the default settings and overriding the global scope.